# Google maps turn-by-turn voice navigation with javascript api

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How we can implement Google maps turn-by-turn navigation service using javascript apis and HTML. im using api v3.

Answer (score 1):

ffwdme.js is a JavaScript toolkit that aims to bring interactive GPS driving directions to the mobile browser.

You can try a current build including a demo page online at dev.ffwdmejs.org

https://github.com/ffwdme/ffwdme.js

Check out this ... may be you find solution here..

Comment: This project is deprecated